# Can we apply mask operation with <p:calendar>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar, mask

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{label.asOfDate}" style="font-weight:bold" />
        <h:outputLabel value="*"
            style="font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:150%" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:calendar id="date" required="true" navigator="true"
        mindate="#{utils.minDate}" pattern="#{label.dateFormat}"
        maxdate="#{utils.maxDate}" value="#{policy.asOfDt}"
        requiredMessage="#{label.asOfDateRequired}" showOn="button">
        <f:validator validatorId="CustomDateValidator" />
    </p:calendar>

</h:column>
```

I want date textfield should in masked format (11/11/2011) with calendar button. Can we apply mask operation with calendar?

Comment: Anybody have any idea????????

Comment: You have to write his name correctly to get heard ;-)

Comment: Vikas, the `@nickname` comment reply works only if that person has posted a comment on the post before (I didn't) and, indeed, then only if you spell the name correctly :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use somehting like this:
`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
          var $ = jQuery;
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $("input[id*='Date']").mask('99/99/9999');
          });
     </script>
     <p:calendar id="documentDate" />
```

`

Answer (score 5):

Since Primefaces 5.0, you can use the calendar's attribute **mask**:

```
mask="99/99/9999"
```

Answer (score 1):

apply `datePattern` attribute

```
datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: this also not working..... i want mask with calender in jsf/prime faces.....it means when user pass date either it automatically take date as dd/MM/yyyy format(user doesn't need to passs in format) or by selecting from calender...

Comment: then go for custom jquery's component

Comment: @Vikas: I am not quite sure if I understand what you are trying to do. The date pattern as suggested by Jigar is exactly for this purpose. You have to clarify your question to get "better" answers. How should the user enter dates? With the text field or with the date chooser or both? What are the allowed date formats a user can put in the text box ... Please be more specific.

Comment: @Matt he wants user to enter date in text box with masked pattern `MM/dd/yyyy` and also he should be able to pick date from the component

Answer (score 1):

As to [this post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13728), it is not possible. The question there is answered by the PF lead developer (so trust him ;-). He suggests to write a composite component in combination with jquery (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

INMO , If you must use additional jquery plugin to achieve this task , you better use jquery for both : calendar and mask (a really little additional code is needed to bind bean value to the input responsible for the calendar)

take a look at this solutions

[Mask the date format when using jQuery UI datepicker](http://ajrawson.com/mask-the-date-format-when-using-jquery-ui-dat)

and

[Small jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/smdvA/16/)

and another one

[Using jQueryUI Datepicker And Input Masking Together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7478296/617373)

Answer (score 0):

You might address this problem by setting the input field to `readonly` to force users to select a date.

Here is the property to add to your input field to force this :

```
readonlyInput="true"
```