# Using jQueryUI Datepicker And Input Masking Together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, masking

First of all check [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/smdvA/) . There is a mask for dates on text box. Also there is a jQueryUI datepicker. They are working very well but when i choose a date with datepicker, text box's mask is disappearing. I want to keep it. Any ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me, Google Chrome on Windows 7. The underlining (mask effect) is lost when a date is entered, but that is normal. Unless you want to keep the underlining?

Comment: I want to keep them . Actually i want to turn it to (for example) 2011-09-19 00:00 . So visitor will be noticed, there is a time (00:00) and it can be changed.

Comment: The problem is that the underscore can't exist in the same place as the letter. Unless there is a way to style each individual letter with underlining. Not sure about that

Comment: No you missunderstood. I don't want to style each letter with an underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this [post](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/adding-time-to-jquery-ui-datepicker). To create this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smdvA/8/).

You can adjust the `javascript` to default to `00:00` if you don't want the current time as the default.

```
date_obj = new Date();
date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours();
date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes();

if (date_obj_mins < 10) { date_obj_mins = "0" + date_obj_mins; }

if (date_obj_hours < 10) {date_obj_hours = "0" + date_obj_hours;}

date_obj_time = "'"+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+"'";

$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ' + date_obj_time });
$(".datepicker").mask("9999-99-99 99:99");
```

Thought I would add that this could be shortened to:

```
date_obj = new Date();
date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date_obj.getHours() : date_obj.getHours();
date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date_obj.getMinutes() : date_obj.getMinutes();

date_obj_time = "'" + date_obj_hours + ":" + date_obj_mins + "'";

$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ' + date_obj_time });
$(".datepicker").mask("9999-99-99 99:99");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smdvA/16/).