# jQuery DatePicker: display an error when input not in proper format

Tags: validation, jquery-ui

I've got a DatePicker that automatically inserts the date in `Mon-dd-yyyy` format and, like so many others, it breaks if an improper format (e.g.  `monddyyyy`, `yyyy-dd-mm`, etc.) is used to enter the date when not in read-only mode.

I want to take DatePicker and have it check to see if the date fits the `Mon-dd-yyyy` format and just spit an error held in a hidden `div` (there's already one for the date being blank) as opposed to going to a stack trace page.

Comment: jQueryUI datepicker already do that for you. You've messed something up: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I'm familiar with how datepicker works; the solution is to put it into read-only mode.  However, I want to make it so the user can manually input the data in the field.

Instead of spitting a simple error, it goes to a stack trace (very unfriendly to the end user).  This is not desired behavior.

Comment: Then maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478296/using-jqueryui-datepicker-and-input-masking-together.

Comment: How did I miss that?  That'll work!  Thank you!

I'll probably mess around with mask definitions, too.

Thank you again!